# Blank spaces in column title in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8cecf67cbab1f15aacdc40e3551dc3a9)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    product VARCHAR,
    quantity DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO inventory
(product, quantity)
VALUES 
('product_01', '800'),
('product_02', '300'),
('product_03', '200'),
('product_04', '500'),
('product_05', '600'),
('product_06', '400');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
product_name  |   product name   |
--------------|------------------|---------
product_01    |   product_01     |
product_02    |   product_02     | 
product_03    |   product_03     |
product_04    |   product_04     |
product_05    |   product_05     |
product_06    |   product_06     |
```

---

My issue is that I am not able to name the column `product name` in the query as I did it in **[MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=5f9c9931f1b11cd18f0da4bca66692be)**. 
As far as I can tell the reason for this is that `postgresSQL` does not accept the **blank space** between **product** and **name**.

I am currently using this query:

```
SELECT
iv.product AS product_name,
iv.product AS 'product name'
FROM inventory iv;
```

Is there a way to make this work in `postgresSQL` or is the only option to not have blank spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes **[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=60ee5a38021c912baab499fe8c379902)**:

```
SELECT iv.product AS product_name,
    iv.product AS "product name"
FROM inventory iv;
```